# Additional fields in CarrierWave Uploader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am trying to add additional fields to the [CarrierWave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) Uploader so that they are stored as part of the Uploader itself and together with the CarrierWave fields, such as `@file`, `@model`, `@storage` etc.

The fields are also version-specific, which is why I'd prefer to be able to access them via `<my_model>.<my_uploader>.attribute` and
`<my_model>.<my_uploader>.versions[:<the_version>]` instead of additional columns in the model.

I did try the [carrierwave-meta gem](https://github.com/gzigzigzeo/carrierwave-meta), but ran into an error with it ( `NoMethodError: undefined method \'original_filename' for #<CarrierWave::Storage::Fog::File:0xab4134c>` )
 that seems to not have been fixed yet.

Any ideas or suggestions on how to best accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% clear what you are trying to do.

when I use carrierwave gem, I do create a path that holds some of that information. In my applaications I normally have a file **app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb**

```
  class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
    include CarrierWave::RMagick
    def store_dir
      # "uploads/image/file/187/"
      "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
    end
    ...
  end
```

from this I always know the model, what type of file, and the id. 
All other info about this model I normally save in the database.

I hope this helps and sets you in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

your error is connected with fog

In my [Picture Uploader](https://github.com/fabriziobertoglio1987/surfcheck/blob/d2501804f8c5ee02a7398031dfdf8b2c1d543e0a/app/uploaders/picture_uploader.rb#L1) I can set an attribute reader and writer

```
class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  storage :file

  def field
    @field
  end

  def field=(field)
    @field = field
  end    

  # attr_accessor :field # for an even shorter way
end
```

The I open the `rails console` to test the model:

```
picture = PictureUploader.new 
=> #<PictureUploader:0x0055804db336e8 @model=nil, @mounted_as=nil>

picture.field=('your text')
=> "your text"

picture.field
"your text"
```

About the versioning and error you are having `'NoMethodError: undefined method \'original_filename' for #<CarrierWave::Storage::Fog::File:0xab4134c>'` I agree with `MZaragoza`

[`CarrierWave::Storage::Fog::File.new`](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/storage/fog.rb#L77) takes three parameters

```
  def store!(file)
    f = CarrierWave::Storage::Fog::File.new(uploader, self, uploader.store_path)
    f.store(file)
    f
  end
```

`uploader`, `self` and `uploader.store_path` so to help us solve this problem you should include your `CarrierwaveUploader` model code and the output of `uploader.store_path`

Thanks a lot